# Change the contents of a file ProjectItem within a Project in a Visual Studio 2015 Extension?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsx

How do I change the contents of a file/`ProjectItem` within a given `Project`? I would like to replace all of its contents with a string.

Comment: Do you want to custom the project in your side or just edit the default one or just use certain tool like Find and Replace in VS IDE which could replace code directly?

Comment: Would you please share the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I want to programmatically change the contents of a file (ProjectItem) within a a VS Extension.

Comment: What do you want to change in your ProjectItem file? Could you find the file in your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

there is have a resolution of this question?

I want to make some changes in `ProjectItem` (CS file) by using VSIX package, and an only single way to do this that I see right now - it's read this file by `FullPath`, make changes, and then save changes.
I know that in `ProjectItem` have `FileCodeModel` property, but it is null.